# How to drop dependency on class method

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection, dependencies, decoupling

I have the 3 following classes:

**Base**

```
module TitleSource

  class Base
    include Comparable

    attr_accessor :company
    attr_accessor :priority
    attr_accessor :target_title

    def initialize(args={})
      self.company = args[:company]
      self.priority = args[:priority]
      self.target_title = args[:target_title]
    end

    def create_contact_source
      raise NotImplementedError
    end

    def <=>(other)
      fetch_value <=> other.fetch_value
    end

    protected def fetch_value
      value
    end

    private def value
      raise NotImplementedError
    end

  end

end
```

**UnmatchedTitle**

```
module TitleSource

  class UnmatchedTitle < Base

    def create_contact_source
      ::ContractorUi::ContactSource.generate_from_unmatched_title(self)
    end

    private def value
      100
    end

  end

end
```

**IncompleteContact**

```
module TitleSource

  class IncompleteContact < Base

    attr_accessor :target_title_name
    attr_accessor :contact

    def initialize(args={})
      super
      self.target_title_name = args[:target_title_name]
      self.contact = args[:contact]
    end

    def create_contact_source
      ::ContractorUi::ContactSource.generate_from_incomplete_contact(self)
    end

    private def value
      10
    end

  end

end
```

I'm currently reading [POODR](http://www.poodr.com/) and came up with this design, which so far served me well.
However, for didactical reasons, I would like to know how I can remove the dependency on `::ContractorUi::ContactSource` if it's worth it and if it should be done.
I don't like the idea of passing it in with the constructor because the entire purpose of `TitleSource` module is to actually generate a `ContactSource`, but would like to hear from more experienced people. Reading the book (and some on-the-field experience) allowed me to understand how much **decoupling** is important

Comment: I would go with: do not worry about dependency injections in ruby. `::ContractorUi::ContactSource` is just a constant (and constant in ruby are not so constant) which helds a reference to the class - you can stub this constant wherever you want. Dependency injections are important when classes are static.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, please note that I wasn't worried in any case, Ruby already allows me to go around any big issue and in my tests I just stubbed generate_xxx for ContactSource class. However I wanted to know from a didactical point of view if it's a good idea to keep the dependency in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that having a single dependency is not a big issue in this case. Based on POODR, this code can react to changes well enough, so keeping the class dependency in this case is fine, expecially considering it's the main purpose of the entire class, to generate an instance of `ContactSource`